# I'm making a level maker with a preview from the code generated by the level maker, how could I do this?

Tags: javascript

I have made a *Level Generator*. Basically there is a 3 by 20 grid of squares, and you can select either one and depending on what you select when you click the button to generate it generate some code for you into a variable (string). It works perfectly but how am I going about to then get that generated code and turn it into a preview.

So far I found out using the keyword `eval()` but this only does the last line? Any ideas?

Here is a picture of what the layout is:
[The Website So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thaxD.png)

The code that I originally had to detect the code was:

```
    if (container.childNodes[index].innerText == 'pos3') {
        if (container.childNodes[index].id == '1 second') {
            text = text + '\n' + 'cube1 = new theCubeCreator(pos3, 0, 2, 1000),'
            //amtselected = amtselected + 1 
        }....
```

Something like that then I would bundle it all up with this

```
    var pos1 = 125 //middle
    var pos2 = 70 //left
    var pos3 = 180 //right
    text = text + '\n' + 'cube1 = new theCubeCreator(pos2, 0, 2, 1000)' // Must add this to make it a end
    var evaluation = eval(text)
    console.log(evaluation);
```

Sorry if this is hard to read or if you want me to send examples.

Comment: You should always avoid using `eval`. However, if you must use `eval`, you should use `new Function(...)` instead.

Comment: @mario_sunny like this? `var evaluation = new Function(eval(text))` This produces a [object Object] error (or unexpected identifier). So it produces this `(function anonymous(
) {
[object Object]
})
`

Comment: `const executable = new Function(text);`. You can then execute your dynamic code by calling the function: `executable()`. However, I am looking at your code and I see no justification for dynamic code execution. Why not just express that logic as a plain Javascript function?

Comment: @mario_sunny would i be able to add parameters like this? `const evaluation = new Function(pos1,pos2,pos3,text)`. I try that and it comes up with an error saying unexpected number? With the output of `(function anonymous(125,70,180
) {
//Code Here (looks like it works)
})`

Comment: See the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function . The `Function` constructor takes a variable number of parameter names as the first arguments. You can therefore do something like `const executable = new Function('param1', 'param2', text)`, then call the executable like `executable(arg1, arg2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is bad practice. You should make an object that holds the functions and a generator function that converts and object into a function.

```js
// object for the function / class you want to run
var data = {
    name: "console.log",
    isClass: false,
    params: ["pos2", 0, 2, 1000],
};

var domParse = {
    name: "DOMParser",
    isClass: true,
    params: ["<div>Hello World</div>", "text/html"],
};

var funcs = {
    DOMParser: (args) => {
        const dom = new DOMParser();
        return dom.parseFromString(...args);
    },
    "console.log": (args) => console.log(...args),
};

// function to generate a function from the object.
function generate({ name, isClass, params }) {
    return funcs[name](params);
}

generate(data); // console.log's pos2 0 2 1000
generate(domParse); // creates a DOM object
```

Answer (score 0):

I took another way than doing eval() *(well i still used eval)*. What I was doing was, to have a variable `let text = ''` then adding onto that variable doing something like this `text = text + \n + '...'`
Already this is bad so i took a different approach. all i changed was instead of having a string variable i would have a Array to store my code. Declearing it like this `let text = []` then using push() to add the code to it, like so `text.push(eval(...))`.

Thats what i did to complete to fix my problem if you have any other way or eisier to follow *(and yes i know this is messy)* then comment (: